# Pressing Submit button Twice clears record in Editor Grid Panel

Tags: extjs

I have an editor grid panel (inside a form) that is adding/deleting dollar amounts of invoice line items. The line item amount from the grid is added to the 'Amount Due' field outside of the grid  but, inside the form.  There maybe an amount in the 'Amount Due' field from somewhere else (not the grid).  I can add and subtract several amounts to the 'Amount Due' field from the grid.  However, when I press the 'Submit' button twice(when it should have been just once) it clears the 'Amount Due' to zero.  How can I make sure that the Submit button does not clear the 'Amount Due' field when accidentally press twice?  What should change in my code?  Thanks for the help.

```
var iLineItemTotalHold = 0;{
        text: 'Submit',
        tooltip:'Submit the line item',
        handler: function(){
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            // Will this code save changes to the database?
            //iLineItemGrid.getStore().commitChanges();
            iLineItemStore.commitChanges();
            // What I want done here is when the amount field in the grid is saved it
            // updates the 'Amount Due' field (outside of the grid) in the form.
            //Does this code update the Amount Due field in the form?

            var iAmountTotalForLineItems = 0;
            var iAmountInDueField = Ext.getCmp('iAmountDue').value;
            var tempTotal = 0;
            var result = 0;
            iLineItemStore.each(function(addAmount){
                iAmountTotalForLineItems += addAmount.get('i_line_item_amt');

            });

            alert('1 iAmountInDueField: ' + iAmountInDueField +' iLineItemTotalHold: '+iLineItemTotalHold + ' iAmountTotalForLineItems: '+ iAmountTotalForLineItems);
            if (iLineItemTotalHold > iAmountTotalForLineItems  ){
                alert ('if');
                tempTotal =  iLineItemTotalHold - iAmountTotalForLineItems;
                result = iAmountInDueField - tempTotal;
                alert('two: '+result+' = '+iAmountInDueField+' + '+tempTotal );

            }

            else if (iLineItemTotalHold < iAmountTotalForLineItems  ){
                alert ('if2');
                tempTotal = iAmountTotalForLineItems - iLineItemTotalHold;
                result = iAmountInDueField + tempTotal;
                alert('3: '+result+' = '+iAmountInDueField+' - '+tempTotal );
            }

            iLineItemTotalHold  =  iAmountTotalForLineItems;

            Ext.getCmp('iAmountDue').setValue(result);
        },
        scope:this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `handler` function add:

```
this.setDisabled(true);
```

To disable your button and prevent any more clicks.

Then add a listeners to your grid's `edit` event that enables the button again when an edit completes. Something like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // your other grid configs
    listeners: {
        edit: function(editor, edit) {
            var form = edit.grid.up('form'),
                button = form.down('button[text=Submit]');

            // enable the button after the grid is edited
            button.setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Then I would also recommend starting your button as `disabled: true`. When the grid is first edited the button will get enabled with that `edit` handler.

Comment: Hello Geronimo, Thanks for your help. I will try out your code suggestions. thanks mike

Comment: @michael No problem. Don't forget to accept (click check image on the left) if this answer works out for you.

Comment: Hello Geronimo, the code is not working.  Here is what I have so far.

Comment: I can't see what you added, but the problem is probably because of the `scope: this` at the end of your handler. You can either get rid of it (I don't see any other scoped calls in your handler that need it but I could be wrong) or you have to get a reference to your button inside the handler and change the disabling function to `yourButtonReference.setDisabled(true)` instead of `this.setDisabled(true)`

Comment: Hello Geronimo, I am having a problem with the listener.